# Php - Post variable values' part at specific index is missing

Tags: php, json, codeigniter, post

I'm making a POST request to my application with a long stringified JSON like below:

```
/////POST PARAMETER VALUE

{"objects":[{"type":"path","originX":"center","originY":"center","left":118.63,"top":252.5,"width":41,"height":139,"fill":null,"overlayFill":null,"stroke":{"source":"function anonymous() {var patternCanvas = fabric.document.createElement('canvas');patternCanvas.width = patternCanvas.height = 10;var ctx = patternCanvas.getContext('2d');ctx.stroke`Style = quotesquare005E7Aquote;ctx.lineWidth` = 5;ctx.beginPath();ctx.moveTo(5, 0);ctx.lineTo(5, 10);ctx.closePath();ctx.stroke(); return patternCanvas;}","repeat":"repeat","offsetX":0,"offsetY":0},"strokeWidth":15,"strokeDashArray":null,"strokeLineCap":"round","strokeLineJoin":"round","strokeMiterLimit":10,"scaleX":1,"scaleY":1,"angle":0,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":1,"selectable":true,"hasControls":true,"hasBorders":true,"hasRotatingPoint":true,"transparentCorners":true,"perPixelTargetFind":false,"shadow":null,"visible":true,"clipTo":null,"path":[["M",40.5,0],["Q",40.5,0,41,0],["Q",41.5,0,41.25,2],["Q",41,4,38,16.5],["Q",35,29,29.5,42],["Q",24,55,21,65],["Q",18,75,15.5,83.5],["Q",13,92,9.5,101.5],["Q",6,111,4.5,118],["Q",3,125,2,128],["Q",1,131,0.5,134],["Q",0,137,0,138],["L",0,139]],"pathOffset":{"x":0,"y":0}}],"background":""}


////// END
```

Every time i do this request, value comes missing. In the server the part that i highlighted is lost. I realised that it's a specific index range at the string. When i give another data in this json stringified format, it looses again the part in that index range. And i'm sure that i'm sending the value complete because i checked it at the request headers.

The problem is not about my code because i tested it with POSTMAN app and the result is same.

Anyone can help about this misterious situation. Is there anything in this value which causes some escaping. And i'm using Codeigniter.

Thanks

Comment: If you've identified the index, could you say what the index is? Is your web server set to only take that number of characters from a POST, perhaps?

Comment: it's like skipping the value between the index 347-370. It's not about that because when i give another data it doesnt loose any value